# Batch adding lines in multiple .txt files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to achieve something in windows batch and I would like your help on that.

I have a bunch of .txt files named like that :

```
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
etc.
```

I would like to link them together with a batch script : adding at the end of each page the link to the next one. For example :

- adding at the end of file_1.txt :
  `next part in page 2`
- adding at the end of file_2.txt :
  `next part in page 3`
- etc.

I know it can be quite simple with this kind of command that simply adds a line at the end of the file :

`ECHO continues in page 2 >>file///C:/file_1.txt`

But I can't manage to find the right loop to batch link them all together in a proper way.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: The single command line `@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion & set "PageNumber=1" & (for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir file*.txt /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do set /A "PageNumber+=1" & type "%%I" & echo next part in page !PageNumber!) >AllFiles.txt & endlocal` makes the job according to your description and writes all file contents into `AllFiles.txt` with `next part in page X` appended after each file content into `AllFiles.txt`. I am 100% sure that this is not what you finally want, but you have now something you can start with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, it's not exactly what I am looking for but it sure helped me understand the process better ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming consecutive numbering of the files, starting with `1`)
Just check if there is another file before adding the link to it:

```
@echo off 
setlocal
REM next line to create a simple test environment:
for /l %%i in (1,1,15) do break>file_%%i.txt

set current=0
:loop
  set /a current+=1
  set /a next=current+1
  if not exist "file_%next%.txt" goto :done 
  >>"file_%current%.txt" echo continues in page %next%
goto :loop
:done
echo ready.
```

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks a lot for your answer. It works great and now I understand how it works and I'm sure I can use it in other situations. Thanks again :)